# What's my mistake?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be any function. Then for some constant $c$, let $f(cx)$ be another function.

$$\int \frac{d(f(cx))}{dx} = f(cx)$$

$$\Rightarrow \int (cf'(x)) = f(cx)$$
$$\Rightarrow c\int f'(x) = f(cx)$$
$$\Rightarrow cf(x) = f(cx)$$

But this obviously isn't true for all functions. (i.e. $f(cx) ≠ cf(x)$ if $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$).

So what's my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\Rightarrow$ and $=$ are two completely different things ;) Also you might want to accept @Poppy's answer, if you don't have any remaining difficulties with this particular question.

Comment: @AlexR I'll be glad to as soon as it allows me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake: $(f(cx))'=cf'(cx)$, for example $(e^{5x})'=5e^{5x}$

Comment: Of course! That was stupid of me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: We all make mistakes :)